# What are some interesting features of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, release-management

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has just been released and we are very eager to enjoy it.

From its features, I have noticed headphone and some other driver support in Mac, new music and video interface, themes etc.

Now, I want to know about some interesting features of this version so that I can enjoy it the best. Can you help me to list them?

#### Rethink:

I asked only for interesting features, not the whole feature list. Whole feature list is in everyone's hand. More precisely, the question is: which features one must try once while exploring Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

- The most exciting for a long time Ubuntu Unity user is that you can
  move it to the bottom.
- You can also control desktop notifications for various applications.
- Ubuntu Software Center has been replaced by GNOME Software.
- You can use Snap packages.

Source: http://itsfoss.com/features-ubuntu-1604/

Answer (score 1):

Quote from OMG Ubuntu

> Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ships with a modified version of Linux 4.4 kernel.
>
> It introduces numerable improvements to system stability, performance, power efficiency, and file system handling, and introduces support for newer Intel and AMD hardware.
>
> Improved Intel Skylake processor support
>       3D support in the virtual GPU driver
>       New driver for Corsair Vengeance K90
>       Support for TPM 2.0 chips
>       Journaled RAID 5 support
>
> It also introduces drivers for the Logitech G29 racing wheel and enables support for hardware features on some newer Toshiba laptops.

Source: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/ubuntu-16-04-download-new-features

Comment: There are several more features described in the following link. But I just asked for interesting features. Thanks.